# How do I show the Drupal Media library file media tag in a paragraph template?

Tags: drupal, twig, taxonomy, templating, media-library

When you have the **Media library** installed in Drupal you have the ability to **tag** your media in order to sort the images and other media. This tag field is a reference to a **Taxonomy term**. I was wondering if it is possible to show this taxonomy term in a **Paragraph template**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the Twig tweak module!

First you get the media targ target id:

```
{% set tid = content.field_img["#items"].entity.get("field_media_tags").0.target_id %}
```

Next you can get the taxonomy term path like this (first you check if there is an actual numeric taxonomy id present, otherwise return an empty string):

```
{% set taxonomy_term_path = (tid matches '/^\\d+$/' ? (path('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', {'taxonomy_term': tid})) : "") %}
```